# List contributors on a proposal below followers

Tags: feature-request, area-51, example-questions, followers

I don't agree that people should be followers prior to voting on or adding example questions on proposals in Area 51.

However, I do think there should be *some* additional accountability, and so propose the following:

#### Under the list of Followers add a list of Contributors that include people who are not followers but have done any of the following:

- Voted on example questions
- Added example questions
- Commented on example questions or the proposal itself
- Edited example questions or the proposal itself

This would also provide another interesting metric - those that are interested in the site, or know enough about the topic to work on it, but are purposefully *not* following it.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree and voted up, showing who voted on questions *could* be like showing who voted on posts here in SOFU, something to analyse a little more.

Who added and comment is already visible on the question and comment itself